# Changing bootstrap active tab color inline

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my issue, I am trying to set the active color of my bootstrap tabs from a class in a custom stylesheet. The css class in question I plan on using is as follows:

```
{
  font: 9pt Tahoma;
  color: #000000;
  border: solid 1px #A8A8A8;
  padding: 3px 12px 4px 12px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is where it gets interesting. When the page is released to clients every client will already have a custom CSS file (This is a update release) with different values - Structurally identical like the CSS class above (apart from the values obviously). This means I cannot add any more attributes to the CSS file and any modifications I make would be done in the .aspx so they would apply to every client.

So my challenge is to change the active color of the tabs to what is in the CSS file in this case it would be: **background-color: red**

The easy solution which is not actually applicable in this situation would be adding another class with the following:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a{
color: red;
}
```

As I mentioned this is not applicable in this situation.

I have thought about trying to read the background color using JQuery on DOM load however I am unsure how I would go about this.

Any guidance would be great! Even just to tell me this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery css() method to read any css attribute of an element, and then again to set an attribute.

https://api.jquery.com/css/

Getting:

```
var theColor = $('.myElement').css("color");
```

Setting:

```
$('.myElement').css("color", "newColor");
```

Answer (score 0):

To use any jQuery's feature like CSS you need to wait DOM load, it's when your browser finished to load your HTML and render the elements 100%.

You have to use jQuery's Selectors rules to find DOM-Nodes, which represents the element found as object. With the node in hand you can work with it.

You have to do something like:

```
// Wait for DOM load
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Getting element by ID and it's color
    var color = $("#my_element_ID").css("color");

    // Setting a color to a group of elements within some rule..
    $("#container div.some_class").css("color", "#FF0000");
});
```

More about jQuery's ".ready()" feature official documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

More about the CSS documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/css/

More about Selectors documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/